# DirectX Game LPD3DX9Sprite Rendering Slow

Tags: c++, performance, directx, rendering

Hey I am trying to build a 2D engine in C++ that can handle thousands of sprites at a time using DirectX as well as SDL. I heard that LPD3DX9Sprite is very efficient and coming from XNA the style is very familiar to me. I was doing some performance testing, batching multiple sprites (same texture and settings) in one time. However, there seems to be some issues with performance and idk why.

```
void Draw()
{

Graphics::direct3D_device->Clear(1, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
Graphics::direct3D_device->BeginScene();

Graphics::SpriteBatch->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

string fs = std::to_string(fps);


for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    Test.Draw();

DrawTextString(32, 64, fs.c_str());

Graphics::SpriteBatch->End();

Graphics::direct3D_device->EndScene();
Graphics::direct3D_device->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

This is my draw code this calls a function that basically calls the DrawMethod of the LPD3DX9Sprite object. Nothing else is really going on in the game just this drawing code.

According to the fps counter I am getting 4fps. Vsync is enabled but the slowdown occurs regardless. Is there anything I can do about this?

I find it odd that this simple test game in C++ with no real logic is crawling compared to a full game engine in C# that runs flawlessly with many sprites rendering.

Comment: What are the contents of `Test.draw();`?

Comment: Graphics::SpriteBatch->Draw(Texture, &SourceRect, &OriginPos, &D3DXVECTOR3(Position.x,Position.y,0), Color);

I'm not even adding any transforms yet for rotating and scaling. Just this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably fair to say this is the culprit:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    Test.Draw();
```

Along with the contents of `Test.draw();`, which you claim to be:

```
Graphics::SpriteBatch->Draw(Texture, &SourceRect, &OriginPos, &D3DXVECTOR3(Position.x,Position.y,0), Color);
```

Despite the fact that this is a relatively simple command, it's a quite expensive command to have to push to the graphics card over-and-over-and-over. I don't know the underlying mechanics of the library you're using, but when commands are written like this, it strongly evokes the style of coding in OpenGL1.x, where vertices and textures are streamed to the graphics card as they're needed, rather than preloading them and simply calling commands to draw the preloaded vertices. You need to research whether the library has the capacity to load this data onto the graphics card ahead of time using Vertex Buffer Objects and other similar constructs.

If it doesn't, then you'll need to learn and implement those concepts yourself.

Also:

> I heard that LPD3DX9Sprite is very efficient...

Generally speaking, any situation where you're using DirectX9 is, by definition, not going to be fast. Not unless you're using the feature set of DX10 and DX11, but in that case, there's no reason to be using DX9 features in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into finding a better method. I guess there really isn't a easy way out.

Comment: ``SpriteBatch`` using [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) for Direct3D 11 is the easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

Note,the method `ID3DXSprite::Draw` doesn't draw/render the sprite to the screen.It just adds the sprite to the list of batched sprites.For info on the methods available in the Interface `ID3DXSprite` see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
 You have to use the `HRESULT Flush()` to draw all the batched sprites.

So your code should be modified like this,

```
void Draw()
{

 Graphics::direct3D_device->Clear(1, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET,D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
 Graphics::direct3D_device->BeginScene();

 Graphics::SpriteBatch->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

 string fs = std::to_string(fps);


 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
   Test.Draw();
 }
 Graphics::SpriteBatch->Flush();//Basically call the Flush Method here
 DrawTextString(32, 64, fs.c_str());

 Graphics::SpriteBatch->End();

 Graphics::direct3D_device->EndScene();
 Graphics::direct3D_device->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Basically, you need to add `Graphics::SpriteBatch->Flush();` this code after the `for` loop.The `Flush()` method will then draw all the batched sprites.

Comment: I have looked at the description and it seems that the Flush(); method is called regardless when the End(); method is called. I also tried your suggestion but the game is still running slow.